# Перехват прерывания

Tags: прерывания, ассемблер

Нужно написать на Ассемблере (компилировать буду через DOS BOX) COM и EXE программы  показывающие возможность перехвата прерывания (замена прерывания 60h действиями, записанными по метке). Не знаю даже, с чего начать...

Comment: очень уж это ваше задание похоже на лабораторную по каким-нибудь микропроцессорам

Comment: Для начала почитайте документацию о семействе процессоров x86 и о его реальном (в отличие от защищённого) режиме.

Comment: @DASHAXXO, [Таблица векторов прерываний](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) это вторая строка в выводе угла на вопрос 

    x86 архитектура прерывания

Советую *вдумчиво* прочитать весь материал по предыдущей и следующих  ссылках того же гугловского ответа (и все смежные темы) перед тем, как задавать новые вопросы.